# Create a custom column in a dict format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I currently have a dataframe like this

| Person | Analysis | Dexterity | Skills |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 174 | 3.76 | 4.12 | 1.20 |
| 239 | 4.10 | 3.78 | 3.77 |
| 557 | 5.00 | 2.00 | 4.40 |
| 674 | 2.23 | 2.40 | 2.80 |
| 122 | 3.33 | 4.80 | 4.10 |

I want to add an column to compile all this information like below

| Person | Analysis | Dexterity | Skills | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 174 | 3.76 | 4.12 | 1.20 | {"Analysis":"3.76", "Dexterity":"4.12", "Skills":"1.20"} |
| 239 | 4.10 | 3.78 | 3.77 | {"Analysis":"4.10", "Dexterity":"3.78", "Skills":"3.77"} |
| 557 | 5.00 | 2.00 | 4.40 | {"Analysis":"5.00", "Dexterity":"2.00", "Skills":"4.40"} |
| 674 | 2.23 | 2.40 | 2.80 | {"Analysis":"2.23", "Dexterity":"2.40", "Skills":"2.80"} |
| 122 | 3.33 | 4.80 | 4.10 | {"Analysis":"3.33", "Dexterity":"4.80", "Skills":"4.10"} |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

rows = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 4},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

# define new column as the json format of another
# also convert to str as that is what you have in your output
df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].astype(str).to_dict(orient='records')
```

`to_dict` has a really nice interface for transforming to JSON format or to other object types. In this instance you are looking for `orient='records'` which is a list of dictionaries.

In your case, you will use:

```py
df['new_column'] = df[
    ['Analysis', 'Dexterity', 'Skills']
].astype(str).to_dict(orient='records')
```